# Sed: how to replace nextline \n symbol in text files?

Tags: text, sed

I need to fix an error and to replace the second tag `</time>` with `</tags>` in an XML file with the following structure:

```
<time>20260664</time>
<tags>substancesummit ss</time>
<geo>asdsadsa</geo>
<time>20260664</time>
<tags>substancesummit ss</time>
<geo>asdsadsa</geo>
```

I'm trying to do it using sed and since I have 2 `</time>` closing tag per item, my idea is to replace `</time><geo>` with `</tags><geo>`.

However there is a next line symbol in between, so I'm using `\n` but it doesn't work:

```
sed 's/time>\n<geo>/tags>\n<geo>/g' old.xml > new.xml
```

Any help?

Comment: How specifically does it not work?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler It doesn't replace the content. The output is the same of the original.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SED: How can I replace a newline (\n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in 1 single sed command like this:

```
sed '/<\/time>/I{n;:A;N;h;/<geo>/I!{H;bA};/<geo>/I{g;s/<\/time>/<\/tags>/i}}' file.txt
```

### Testing

If your input file.txt is like this:

```
<time>20260664</time>
<tags>substancesummit ss
</time>

<Geo>asdsadsa</geo>
<time>30260664</time>
<tags>substancesummit st</timE>
<geo>bsdsadsa</geo>
```

Then **output** of above command will be:

```
<time>20260664</time>
<tags>substancesummit ss
</tags>

<Geo>asdsadsa</geo>
<time>30260664</time>
<tags>substancesummit st</tags>
<geo>bsdsadsa</geo>
```

It covers multiple new line characters (`\r` or `\n`) in any combination between `</time>` and `<geo>`

PS: Above sed command is doing ignore care search/replace, in case you don't want that then just remove `I` flag from sed command or just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$ sed -n '1h; 1!H; $ {g; s/<\/time>\n<geo>/<\/tags>\n<geo>/g; p;}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a character that you definitely don't use in the file, try to replace \n with it, do your sed work and replace back. tr works really well for that

```
cat old.txt | tr '\n' '#' | sed 's/time>#<geo>/tags>#<geo>/g' | tr '#' '\n' > new.txt
```

I use # as replace character.

Answer (score 0):

sed usually edits lines, and it is a bit harder to make it understand multiple lines at once, as you are.  Instead, how about fixing up the broken lines more directly, with something like this:

```
/<tags>/ s@</time>@</tags>@
```

This will replace `</time>` with `</tags>` only on lines which also contain `<tags>`.  Note that I used `@` instead of `/` as the delimiter for the substitution command, to avoid a need to escape the slashes in the XML we're trying to replace.

Answer (score 0):

you can use`awk` instead

```
$ awk -vRS="</geo>" '{gsub(/<\/time>.<geo>/,"</tags>\n<geo>")}1' ORS="</geo>" file
<time>20260664</time>
<tags>substancesummit ss</tags>
<geo>asdsadsa</geo>
<time>20260664</time>
<tags>substancesummit ss</tags>
<geo>asdsadsa</geo>
```

First, I can see that `</geo>` ends each block, so make this the record separator. After that, substitute what is required. Lastly, put `</geo>` back as the output record separator (ORS).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you sidestep the issue with trying to match the linebreaks and instead try matching the line with the opening `<tags>` tag and the content after it up to the (non-)matching `</time>` tag? Like

```
# untested, written from scratch
sed 's/<tags>(.*)<\/time>/<tags>\1<\/tags>/g' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's,<\([^>]*\)>\([^<]*\)</[^>]*>,<\1>\2</\1>,g' tags.xml
```

This replaces in the same line an

```
(opening tag)(content)(closing tag)
```

with

```
(opening tag)(content)(closing tag)
```

but the closing tag is always the same tag, as the opening tag.

It can fail if more than one tag-pair is found in the file.

In Detail, it searches for something, starting with '<', followed by the name of the tag without closing it '>', followed by the content, which is everything until '<'.